# Converting classes won't work java

Tags: java

I am new to converting classes. I am trying to convert from one variable to another using methods. Currently, I'm not sure how to convert the double to an int and then round it and how to convert `boolean` to an `int` so `0 = false` and `1 = true`. Can anyone help?

My code:

```
public class MethodsOverloading {

    public int convert (String s) {
        System.out.println("This is a string "+ s); // Hoping to display 100 as a string
        return 0;
    }

    public int convert(double d) {
        System.out.println("This is an int "+ d); // Want to display 99.6 rounded to 100 (so its an int)
        return 0;
    }

    public int convert (boolean b) {
        System.out.println("This is an int "+(b)); // hoping to return as an int with 0 = false and 1 = true
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MethodsOverloading overload = new MethodsOverloading();
        overload.convert("100");
        overload.convert(99.6);
        overload.convert(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you returning 0 in all of your methods?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
System.out.println("This is an int "+ Math.round(d/100.0)*100); // Want to display 99.6 rounded to 100 (so its an int)
```

for the double method, and

```
System.out.println("This is an int "+(b?1:0)); // hoping to return as an int with 0 = false and 1 = true
```

for the int method.

Comment: Don't use `Math.round`. This will return a `long` rather than an `int`.

Comment: Obviously OP's in learning phase. Teaching/explaining ternary expression is not recommended. It would be better to use `if/else`.

Answer (score 1):

boolean:

```
if ( trueExpression ){ return 1;}
else { return 0;}
```

in the next line, you contradict yourself:

```
System.out.println("This is an int "+ d); // Want to display 99.6 rounded to 100 (
```

99.6 is not an int. 100 is. so, if you want to display 99.6, you'll need

```
"this is a double: " + (double)d
```

inform the jvm that it's a double, and it should work.

Comment: That line of code may not print `99.6` but `99.599987561464` or similar.

Comment: Or using `System.out.printf("This is a double: %.2f\n", d);`

Comment: Indeed. But seeing the question, I doubt the OP is aware of this option, where-as he may have seen the possibility of rounding already (just didn't remember the specifics).

Answer (score 0):

You can get an integer from a `String` using this method:

```
Integer.parseInt(s);
```

To get an integer from a `double`, you can use the `ceil` method from `Math`, and cast its result to an integer:

```
(int) Math.ceil(d)
```

And, to convert a `boolean` to an integer you can use this simple logic:

```
if (b) // this is equivalent to `if (b == true)`
    return 1;
else
    return 0;
```

Note that it is recommended to use `if (b)` instead of `if (b == true)`.

Comment: (int)d wouldn't allow him to print 99.6

Comment: @m0skit0 IMO `if/else` is better for starters rather than ternary expressions.

Comment: `(b == false)` you mean `(!b)`? "Teaching" stuff like `== true` or `== false` should be avoided.

Comment: @Tom Edited with all suggestions.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yeah, I kind of agree, although that's not a valid reason

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like that:

```
public int convert (boolean b) {
  // conversion: 1 - true, 0 - false
  int result = b ? 1 : 0;

  // debug information printing out 
  System.out.println("This is an boolean " + result); 
  // Do you really want to return 0 in any case? 
  // Returning conversion result looks far better
  return result; 
}
```